# GCP stackdriver email notifications format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We have setup few log based metric monitoring in GCP.
For one metric, the format of email notifications is different than in the other metric. This is for both alert recovered notification and alert generation notification.
Any idea why the format is coming as different ?
Thanks.

plain text email for one metric:

[image]

html email for other metric:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details about configured monitoring metrics.